# How to clear inner class attributes on parent creation

Tags: python, inner-classes

I have a nested class setup like the code snippet bellow.

```
class test:
    class child:
         some_variable = None
```

When I try to call this code from another .py file like bellow

```
from testing import test
t = test()
t.child.some_variable ="123"
t = test()
print(t.child.some_variable)
```

I get the output

```
123
```

I expected to get None, or at least an error message. I have tried to solve it with the following approach but the problem persists with the same output.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child()
    class child:
        some_variable = None
        def __init__(self):
            self.some_variable = ""
```

How can I initiate a new child class when I am calling the parent class?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here, but classes inside classes is generally bad practice

Comment: @bphi if he is doing some meta programming, it makes sense.  Although that does not seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By don't having it as an inner class, but as a separate class and then an instant attribute:

```
class child_class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_variable = None

class test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.child = child_class()


t = test()
t.child.some_variable = "123"
t = test()
print(t.child.some_variable) # prints None
```

Or alternative you can have a inner class, but still you have to create an instance attribute:

```
class test:
    class child_class:
        def __init__(self):
            self.some_variable = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.child = self.child_class()

t = test()
t.child.some_variable = "123"
t = test()
print(t.child.some_variable) # also prints None
```

Comment: Wanted each class to "own" its subclasses inside of themselves. But I guess depending on the feedback given that its not a optimal solution. So adopted my code to this solution.

Comment: @RasmusEkman You can also move the class inside the parent class and call `self.child = self.child_class()`. See edit.